# How do I get my Wanhao Duplicator 6 / Maker Ultimate to lower bed at end of print?

Tags: g-code

What would be the end g-code so that I can get my Monoprice Ultimate (Wanhao D6) to lower the bed to midway on the frame or something easier to remove the print? The default end position is very high up at the top.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your ending script add the line below and change Z200.0 to your max Z height.  This will rapid to the given value using absolute coordinates.  I added G90 in case G91 was previously set so it did not do a relative move.  I'm not positive if G91 is modal in printer firmwares or not but the G90 should not hurt anything.

```
G90 G0 Z200.0
```

Comment: *This will rapid to...* should that be *raise*?

Comment: No, G0 uses rapid feed rate.  G1 uses the feed rate given by F.  Also a Z value like this does not mean we are raising something.  The head will raise to 200mm on a printer like the i3 but the bed will lower on a printer like the DaVinci 2.